# Private Coupons Generated work for multiple accounts (but they shouldn't)

Tags: sitecore-commerce

It seems that private promotion coupons aren't working on our site as I expected based on the documentation

(https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/work-with-promotions.html) `A private coupon is a discount code that is assigned to a single customer.`

My understanding is that  I am supposed to be able to generate a specific number of codes that start and end with a prefix and suffix I set, and give each one of the codes to one specific customer, and the code will then be tied to their account. However, the private codes I created appear to work just like a normal public code and give anyone who uses them the discount if the same code is input by multiple users.

Has anyone run into this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I know from private coupons and how we use them, everyone who has the code can use it.
Each private coupon is has an individual code and can be only used one time. After it is used in an order process it cannot be used anymore.
 To "bind" it to a customer you can just send the code to a specific customer e.g. via email campaign

Comment: Thanks, Christian. I missed being notified of your response somehow, but I appreciate it.